# Durandal - specify view for module in viewmodel

Tags: javascript, durandal

I'm trying to find a way to specify the location of the view for a viewmodel. I have a collection of viewModels, all with a common ancestor.

I want them all to use the same view, which itself will build the page up using dynamic composition.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout Durandal's View Locator documentation at http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Locator/

If I understand your requirements correctly than adding either a `getView()` function or a `viewUrl` property to the vms should do the job.

`getView()` example (doing the opposite from what you want by adding multiple views per vm, but you get the point).

http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/view-composition/getView

```
var getView = ko.computed(function(){
    var roleViewMap = {
      'default': 'viewComposition/getView/index.html',
      role1: 'viewComposition/getView/role1.html',
      role2: 'viewComposition/getView/role2.html'
    };

    this.role = (role() || 'default');

    return roleViewMap[this.role];
});
```

`viewUrl` example

http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/view-composition/SO16483013

```
function viewUrl(){
 this.role = (role() || 'default');

     var roleViewMap = {
       'default': 'samples/viewComposition/SO16483013/index.html',
       role1: 'samples/viewComposition/SO16483013/role1.html',
       role2: 'samples/viewComposition/SO16483013/role2.html'
     };

     return roleViewMap[this.role];
}
```

Comment: I've looked at that page a few times today - didn't see it there until now. It works exactly how I wanted it to, Thankyou!